# Unable to load data in UI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am making a CRUD application using nodeJS and Mongodb

when i use the GET request from postman to add data to the mongodb database it is succesfully done

but when i go to localhost and do the "add_user" from form name and email is not adding to the database it says

{
"message": "userdb validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required."
}

is there any problem in my model.js file or something else

GITHUB code link
https://github.com/priyanshu740/CRUD-

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you executing the application? Like `node index`, or something else

Comment: nodemon index.js @DevMayukh

Comment: can you send the package.json file?

Comment: yeah...uploaded on github

Comment: you forgot to add the .env file, with MONGO=<your_uri_string>

Comment: i didnt push it in github but i have added that file and MONGO=<uri> in my confige.env file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236809/discussion-between-priyanshu-and-devmayukh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after deugging for a long time, I got the answer.
It's actually a very funny one.

Locate to views/include/_user.ejs
there, you can see a form, and in that form,

1. the input form for name, add the attribute name="name"
2. the input for email, add the attribute name="email"

That will fix it

Comment: damn that's so silly mistake through hahaha and thanks a lot mate once again

Comment: after submitting form i am getting a message like this  "message": "No write concern mode named 'majority>' found in replica set configuration" what is this about?

Comment: It seems like you are using a local instance of MongoDB. The above uri applies if you use mongodb atlas.

Comment: So how to fix this? I tried removing w=mejority but didn't work